# Psedit on a item created with the New-Item cmdlet throws exception

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

When I create a new file using the `New-Item` cmdlet and want to edit it within PowerShell ISE using `psedit` I receive the following exception:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:7 char:13
+             $psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.Files.Add($_.FullName) > $nul ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullReferenceException
```

**Code:**

```
New-Item readme.txt
psedit readme.txt
```

**PsVersionTable:**

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.494                                                                                                                                             
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                   
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.494                                                                                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Is this a known Bug? Any workaround?

Comment: try readme.ps1, I think psedit is intended to be used to edit scripts

Comment: @MickyBalladelli You are right, if I create a `ps1`, I am able to edit the file using `psedit`. However, I use psedit all the time to edit e. g. configs and readmes. If I create the empty file using Windows Explorer I am able to use psedit as well.

Comment: Interesting, if readme.txt is empty, it fails. However if it contains some text, then it works. I tried with `"Hello World" | Out-File readme.txt` followed `by
psedit readme.txt`

Comment: Yes, If I open the file using e. g. notepad and add a single character, I am able to psedit into it...

Comment: I think you hit a bug in V5. I just tried with V4 and it works.

Comment: @MickyBalladelli True. Looks like the workaround is to create the file using `'' | Out-File readme.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a PowerShell **V5** bug since its working fine on PowerShell V4 (see the [comment from Micky Balladelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968672/psedit-on-a-item-created-with-the-new-item-cmdlet-throws-exception/38969490#comment65292588_38968672)). A workaround is to create the file using the `Out-File` cmdlet:

```
'' | Out-File readme.txt
psedit readme.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the following works without an issue and opens a new tab in the ISE with the readme.txt:

```
New-Item Readme.txt -ItemType file
psedit Readme.txt
```

PSVersiontable:

```
    Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
PSVersion                      4.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: `-ItemType file` is implicitly used when creating a file with an extension. I tried to explicitly specify the `ItemType` but receive the same exception.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Powershell 5.0 issue maybe? 
Also if i use new-item without "-ItemType File" it requests a type even with extension, hence i included the "-ItemType File"

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a PowerShell 5.0 issue.